# how to convert 44/5 in C# to get decimal values?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to convert 44/5 in C# to get decimal values actual result will be like this 13.75 but i got only 13

need 13.75 how to get 
 tried many solutions but not possible to get please help to find

-----------Tried Methods--------------------

```
protected void txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cal= 55 / 4;  //13

    decimal cal= 55 / 4;  //13

    string cal= String.Format("{0:0.00}", 55 / 4);  //13.00

    decimal cal= decimal.Floor(55 / 4);     //13

    SalesPrice.Text = cal.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You're performing integer arithmetic. Make either of the operands a decimal, e.g. `55m/4`. (This is a duplicate of *many* questions, but I don't have time to find one right now.)

Comment: did you try 55/4.0 or 55.0/4?

Comment: @captainsac: Those would give a result of a `double`; the OP wants a `decimal`.

Comment: never mind. she wants the result as 13.75.. can change the data type of cal variable.

Comment: @captainsac: Or change your suggestion which uses a `double` literal to use a `decimal` literal instead...

Comment: Thanks I got the answer by trying both the ways 55m/4 and 55.0/4 thanks for the help

Comment: @JonSkeet  I figured out the answer but What this is called in C#? Is it boxing and unboxing thing or ?

Comment: @RahulNikate: No, there's no boxing here at all. What are you asking about?

Comment: @JonSkeet Why do we need to mention decimal while doing this arithmetic. Any specific name in C# specs for this type of conversion. I think it's type casting.

Comment: @RahulNikate: Not sure what you mean by "need to mention" - you can have `var cal = 55m / 4;` and it will still be a `decimal`. It's just the type of the literal (`55m` is a `decimal` literal) and normal operator overload resolution.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing: `decimal cal = 55m/4;`

Comment: thanks got answer  by using your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
decimal cal= (decimal)55 / 4;  //13.75
```

Comment: ya this idea also works thanks